# Select several tag items with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the next html:

```
<html>
<body>
...
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#39</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-29T07:30:02+01:00">Apr 29, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #39</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#38</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-28T07:30:00+01:00">Apr 28, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #38</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#37</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-27T07:30:02+01:00">Apr 27, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #37</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I want iterate over each article tags and I really get with:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = get("https://example.com")


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
issues = soup.find_all("article", {"class": "issue"})

for issue in issues:
    print (issue)
```

And now I want select from each article tag the span tag with class 'description', but when I call 'issue.span' only select the first tag found.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean as follows. using CSS selectors in combination? I use a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to combine selectors such that you get `span.description` children of `article.issue`. This way of writing means you will only get descriptions where they exist so no additional test is needed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html>
<body>
...
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#39</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-29T07:30:02+01:00">Apr 29, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #39</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#38</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-28T07:30:00+01:00">Apr 28, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #38</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
<article class="issue">
<div class="issue-nr">#37</div>
<div class="issue-date">
<time datetime="2018-04-27T07:30:02+01:00">Apr 27, 2018</time>
</div>
<div class="issue-title">
<h1>
<a href="/" rel="" target="" title="Title"><span class="subject">The... - #37</span>
<span class="description">
 –
Blah, Bleh, Blih ...
</span>
</a></h1>
</div>
</article>
...
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
descriptions = soup.select('article.issue span.description')
descriptions = [description.text for description in descriptions]
print(descriptions)
```

Result:

[image]

---

For yours, you would  need to select the `span.description` from the `issue`

```
print([issue.select('span.description') for issue in issues])
```

Comment: +1 for using css. I sometimes think beautiful soup is a conspiracy to keep python users from learning css.

Comment: @pguardiario  Thanks. I am new to python but can’t imagine not using css.

Comment: That's probably because you're a legit coder as opposed to casual users who mostly just paste stuff from SO :)